# Should an Class utilize it's own factory?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm building up a hierarchy of device classes(linux 'block' devices).  My Device factory has evolved from just being a way to create various device sub classes from different inputs, into a builder of sorts.  It populates a lot of the data.  My question is, should the create() method on an Lvm class use the device factory to populate this information?  Or should I consider moving all this logic into the Device sub-classes themselves?  See, you can instantiate an lvm object with just enough info to create one on disk, but once it's created more information is available and needs to be populated into the object.

Comment: follow http://sscce.org/ and edit your question

Comment: Haha, I thought that was spam and completely ignored it till now.  I drink a lot... Anyway, thanks for the link and your right.  I know better.  I'll see what happens this weekend.